# Loading specific module from external project

Tags: erlang

I have a project composed of several apps. The apps use some of the same records and functions to communicate, so I would like to make a module "shared" between them.
I tried using the `code:add_path` and `code:load_file` functions but the app still crashes with an `undef` error when trying to access those shared functions.
The apps are started using different escript methods (`rebar3 shell` and `make run` with erlang.mk).

1. How do I add an external module in the makefile method (I know in rebar3 there's an `{extra_src_dirs, []}` option)?
2. What is the best way to load and add the shared module in code in runtime?

EDIT:
I also tried using `code:load_abs` and adding `-pa <file_path>` to vm.args

Comment: Have you tried using `-pa` or `-pz`  as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20570508/whats-the-difference-between-codeadd-path-and-using-pa-on-the-command-line ...?

Comment: @Agus I'm starting the apps by running one with ```make run``` and the other with ```rebar3 shell```. I know I can add ```-pa | -pz``` to rebar in the ```vm.args``` file, but where should I do this for the makefile? Should I switch to ```erl -boot myapp```? EDIT: I should probably use ```ERL_FLAGS=" -args_file```, right?

Answer (score 3):

I succeeded by simply using `code:load_abs("<file_path>.beam")`, and having a symlink to the original `.erl` file with the other source code. According to [the documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code#load_abs-1) the extension needs to be omitted, which threw me off.

EDIT: **use a hardlink instead**, for some reason my changes stop taking affect at some point between the files..